# how to inner query UNION with GROUP BY and WHERE Condition

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

My **[sqlfiddle](http://goo.gl/5oDrqt)**

my DB schema and query online

**Query 1**

```
SELECT pk_video_master_id AS _id,
video_title AS title1,
COUNT(fk_video_master_id) AS sub_title_1,
SUM(video_detail_length) AS sub_title_2,
-1007 AS module 
FROM tbl_video_master 
LEFT JOIN tbl_video_detail ON fk_video_master_id = pk_video_master_id 
WHERE title1 LIKE '%a%' GROUP BY _id
```

**Query 2**

```
 SELECT pk_surveys_id AS _id ,
 surveys_title AS title1,
 surveys_end_date AS sub_title_1,
 COUNT(fk_survey_detail_survey_id) AS sub_title_2, 
-1006 AS module
 FROM tbl_surveys 
 LEFT JOIN tbl_survey_detail ON fk_survey_detail_survey_id = pk_surveys_id 
 WHERE title1 LIKE '%a%' GROUP BY _id
```

i want to UNION this 2 query i have also create

```
SELECT pk_video_master_id AS _id,
video_title AS title1,COUNT(fk_video_master_id) AS sub_title_1,
SUM(video_detail_length) AS sub_title_2,-1007 AS module 
FROM tbl_video_master 
LEFT JOIN tbl_video_detail ON fk_video_master_id = pk_video_master_id 
UNION 
SELECT pk_surveys_id AS _id ,surveys_title AS title1,
surveys_end_date AS sub_title_1,
COUNT(fk_survey_detail_survey_id) AS sub_title_2, 
-1006 AS module
FROM tbl_surveys 
LEFT JOIN tbl_survey_detail ON fk_survey_detail_survey_id = pk_surveys_id 
WHERE title1 LIKE '%a%' GROUP BY module
```

but its return only 2 record

my desire output is search in both table TITLE1 field

so please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You removed the GROUP BY from query1. Most other DBMS would have raised an error, but SQLite just returns one record with random information instead. You also removed the WHERE clause by the way.

So glue your *complete* query 1 to your *complete* query 2. And use UNION ALL instead of UNION, because there are no duplicates to remove anyhow.

```
SELECT pk_video_master_id AS _id,
video_title AS title1,COUNT(fk_video_master_id) AS sub_title_1,
SUM(video_detail_length) AS sub_title_2,-1007 AS module 
FROM tbl_video_master 
LEFT JOIN tbl_video_detail ON fk_video_master_id = pk_video_master_id 
WHERE title1 LIKE '%a%' GROUP BY _id
UNION ALL
SELECT pk_surveys_id AS _id ,surveys_title AS title1,
surveys_end_date AS sub_title_1,
COUNT(fk_survey_detail_survey_id) AS sub_title_2, 
-1006 AS module
FROM tbl_surveys 
LEFT JOIN tbl_survey_detail ON fk_survey_detail_survey_id = pk_surveys_id 
WHERE title1 LIKE '%a%' GROUP BY module;
```

Here is your SQL fidlle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/03ecc/14.

Comment: hey @Thorsten Kettner can you help me one time more? in this query last GROUP BY module replace with GROUP BY _id an UNION ALL after this new query how can i get cont by module ???

Comment: Now, that you mention this... I hadn't looked at your groups closely enough. When grouping then every selected part should either be grouped by or aggregated or a constant (or an expression consisting of these). However SQLite allows to select further columns. For these you get a random match. So let's look at your first select (before union): You group by pk_video_master_id. You aggregate fk_video_master_id with COUNT and video_detail_length with SUM. -1007 is a constant. But title1 isn't any of these. You get a random title of the matching records. In your second query [to be continued]

Comment: In your second query you even group by -1006, i.e. you don't group at all, because all records have the same module number -1006. So you get one record with a random pk_surveys_id, a random surveys_end_date, and the count of non-null fk_survey_detail_survey_ids. Please decide what you want to group by for both queries. You can also group by two or more columns: GROUP BY _id, video_title. Or aggreagate the non-grouped columns: MAX(video_title). I know, it makes no difference here, because the video title is the same for every _id. But to always either group by or aggregate helps avoid errors.